# Does version of Mercurial matter?

Tags: mercurial

I was given a clone of a Mercurial repository and I don't know what version of Mercurial the repository was created on. Are all Mercurial repositories backwards compatible? I.e. can I install the latest version of Mercurial on my machine and be able to interact with the repository OK or could there potentially be issues not knowing the version of Mercurial the repository was created under?

Comment: When you say "I was given a clone", do you mean that you ran `hg clone <repo>` or that someone zipped up a directory and sent it to you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I write blog post on this topic:

- http://brain-break.blogspot.com/2011/09/new-mercurial-repository-format.html
- http://brain-break.blogspot.com/2009/09/new-mercurial-repository-format-fncache.html

Shortly currently new HG version can operate on old repositories locally but revert sentence false.

The wire protocol does not change across HG versions so you can **clone**, **pull**, **push** from any version of HG to any version of HG that run on **http://** and **ssh://** protocols.

If you access a repository on your local filesystem and it is not supported, you get error message like:

```
abort: requirement 'fncache' not supported!
```

This controlled by keywords from requires files:

```
  $ cat repo/.hg/requires
revlogv1
store
fncache
dotencode
```

Comment: When using SSH, it is the version of Mercurial on the server that is important. So you can use an old version locally to talk with a new Mercurial repository on the server. I've edited your answer to reflect this.

Comment: @MartinGeisler Much chanks for correction. It is hard to take in account all things when try to save personal time when answer at SO.

Answer (score 3):

The Mercurial developers go to [great lengths](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CompatibilityRules) to insure backwards compatibility.

Changes that could affect compatibility are listed in [UpgradeNotes](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/UpgradeNotes) as well.